# Three js TextureLoader not working when trying to render sprites.

Tags: javascript, three.js, sprite

I'm trying to do Sprites in Three.js but cant seem to get TextureLoader to load the .jpg properly. The single color works, just not the image. I'v done some searches but couldn't really find anything specific the Sprites or Texture loader. Getting an error:

```
Failed to execute 
'texImage2D' on 'WebGLRenderingContext': The cross-origin image 

ERROR 
:GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glGenerateMipmap: Can not generate mips
255index.html:1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-000001B1C9621FE0]RENDER WARNING: 
texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 
and have incompatible texture filtering.
index.html:1 WebGL: too many errors, no more errors will be reported to the 
console for this context.


<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>

<script src="js/three.js"></script>
<script>
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: 
document.getElementById('myCanvas'), antialias: true});
renderer.setClearColor(0x000000);
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(35, window.innerWidth / 
window.innerHeight, 300, 10000);

var scene = new THREE.Scene();

var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
scene.add(light);

var light1 = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
scene.add(light1);

var spriteMap = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'flake.png' ); 

var spriteMaterial = new THREE.SpriteMaterial( {    color: 0xffffff } );
var sprite = new THREE.Sprite( spriteMaterial );           
sprite.scale.set(500, 500, 1);
sprite.position.z = -1000;

var sprite = new THREE.Sprite( spriteMaterial );
sprite.scale.set(500, 500, 1);
sprite.position.z = -1000;

scene.add( sprite );

window.onresize = function () {
        camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    };

render();

function render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
};

</script>
```